# How to automate the deploy several meteor apps to my custom server?

Tags: nginx, meteor, linode

I want to deploy several  meteor apps without having to create separate nginx vhost file for each app manually. Till now i have hosted multiple meteor apps and created multiple vhost file manually for eg,

server {

listen                *:80;

server_name           test1.com;

location / {

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
```

// some other config
}

}

how can we automate this process like meteor provides. Once we run 
[meteor deploy test] it automatically creates subdomain and app runs at "test.meteor.com" 
is there any process to create similar in my custom server?
for now it would be great to create automatic vhost file pointing to the meteor apps running in the server.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there isn't a process like this to strictly what you want.

There are a few projects that are close, based on docker that create a 'private heroku'

- [Dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku)
- [Flynn](https://flynn.io/)
- [Deis](http://deis.io/)
- [Meteor-UP](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) (No subdomains/multi tenancy)

These projects allow you to use the meteorite buildpack to git push your project to the server, and it would build it and run it on a subdomain.

All 3 require a bit of a setup. Flynn and Deis recommend at least 3 servers for one cluster. Dokku may need an plugin to easily create subdomains.

There isn't anything for Meteor specifically designed for this purpose.

Meteor Development Group (MDG) intends to release a commercial product that can do what `meteor deploy` can do called [Galaxy](http://roadmap.meteor.com). You could also wait for that. Keep in mind it will be a commercial product though.